# Registering beans dynamically by reading a config in springboot starter module

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I have a springboot starter module which is reading a config file and using that I'm trying to build a new beans of arbitrary type and add them to the bean factory.

```
@Configuration
class SomeConfig implements BeanFactoryAware {

    BeanFactory beanFactory 

    @Autowired
    ConfigData configData

    @Override
    void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
         this.beanFactory = beanFactory      
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void addMoreBeans() {
        ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory
        configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton('someObject', new SomeObject())
    }   
}


@RestController //( in the application )
class SomeController {
   @Autowired
   SomeObject someObject // this is null.
}
```

When I try to access the bean of type 'SomeObject' in the the SpringBootApplication ( in a controller bean) which is using the starter module which contains the above config bean, it's not autowired.

I can see that , it initializes these beans later in the startup process but not in time for the autowire to work.

Is there anyway to force the beans in the starter module to initialize first. ?

Comment: I try to test the code. I found that `BeanFactory` do not have the `registerSingleton ` method. My spring is 4.3.10.

Comment: It is a **ConfigurableBeanFactory**. Edited my question above.

Answer (score 0):

**The `addMoreBeans` may be run before the `setBeanFactory` is run.**

So you may be write the code as follows:

```
@Configuration
class SomeConfig implements BeanFactoryAware {

    BeanFactory beanFactory 

    @Autowired
    ConfigData configData

    @Override
    void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory
        beanFactory.registerSingleton('someObject', new SomeObject()    
    }
}
```

**The `@Bean` may be a better way.**

```
@Configuration
class SomeConfig2 {
    @Bean
    public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
        return new SomeObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, a null pointer will be thrown. It does register eventually but just not in time for the autowire to work in the @RestController bean.

Comment: The second option won't work for what I'm looking for, because I don't know the type of the bean and the type of the bean is driven by configuration.

Comment: You can use the **Reflect API** to load the type dynamicly in the `getSomeObject ` method. But I do not know  whether It is OK.